# Black & white TV episode where invisible aliens experiment on humans

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I'm trying to find any info about a black and white (therefore I assume 1950s or 1960s) TV show episode where the protagonist can see aliens that everyone else can't see and these invisible aliens are experimenting on humans as the humans go about their day unaware. Like one experiment might have had some alien contraption on a person's head and they say something about having a headache or such.

I thought it might have been a *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits* episode, but if it is then I can't figure out which one it is. Does this description ring a bell for anyone?

Edit: I recall the protagonist (a man) walking through a bar talking to different people as he went. The bar was on the left of the screen and each person mentioned some ailment they had but he couldn't see the aliens yet. Later he walks the opposite direction through the bar but can now see the aliens and their devices on people. The vibe was disturbing, not light-hearted, like anything could be more horrible than we imagine. I don't think the show was meant for child audiences, though I saw it as one and I think it has stuck in my head because it seemed so disturbing. I probably would have seen it in the mid or late 80s but I grew up watching much much older shows (ie *Leave it to Beaver*, *Dragnet*, *I Love Lucy*, etc). The show was in English and would have been some type of re-run aired on an American TV station (unsure if it was broadcast or cable).

Comment: B&W with invisible aliens experimenting on humans, including a bar, would match ["Mr. Dingle the Strong"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYSIQPjaFMk) from *The Twilight Zone*, but I think only Mr. Dingle actually has the experiment done on him.

Comment: There was an _Outer Limits_ episode called "Controlled Experiment", with Carroll O'Conner, Barry Morse and Grace Lee Whitney. The characters played by O'Connor and Morse were Martians studying humans, and they had a gadget that let them manipulate time. When they froze time, they could walk around without people being able to see them. This was one of the very rare light-hearted, comic episodes of the series.

Comment: Thanks, FuzzyBoots and user 888379. Out of the episodes of _The Twlight Zone_ and _The Outer Limits_, those seem the closest but aren't it, so I'm starting to think it must've been a different old series. I've tried checking the episode lists for _One Step Beyond_ and _Science Fiction Theater_ and I don't think it was those. Tried doing the same for _Suspense_ but there's less episode synopses online.

Comment: Apart from not being black and white, and the date aired, this sounds an awful lot like the Voyager episode Scientific Method.

Comment: I totally agree that the plot sounds just like it, DafyddNZ. (Moo suggested this as well but I don't know if they deleted their proposed answer since I don't see it below anymore.) I've been trying to find where the writers of that episode got the idea from. This is a good review of the episode (and it mentions similarities to other Trek episodes) but doesn't cover the origin for the idea of the plot: https://them0vieblog.com/2017/02/03/star-trek-voyager-scientific-method-review/ One of the writers on that episode was Sherry Klein, so I tried finding interviews of her but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: If it was a short story (and not a TV show or movie), I would have suggested "Don't Look Now" by Henry Kuttner. This story may have been inspiration for an episode of something, but I'll leave it to someone else to find (I don't know where to start on that...)

Comment: Hmm, "Don't Look Now" had invisible aliens and a bar but no experiments/contraptions on humans. It does seem though that the premise for the episode in question (and later content in _The Twilight Zone_, _The Outer Limits_, and _Star Trek_ (Voyager, TNG, TOS) all were just using a combo of 2 tropes: "Unwitting Test Subject" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnwittingTestSubject and "Invisible to Normals" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InvisibleToNormals , so the idea in general is not unique, but I do recall enough specifics that it doesn’t match any of the suggestions.